# google map version 2 does not work with fragment

Tags: android, google-maps

I do not know, what i am doing wrong in either my manifest, activity or xml to load map version 2,

i found multiple exceptions if you see my concise logcat,

```
E/AndroidRuntime(16522): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(16522): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activityComponentInfo{com.production.MyApp/com.project.MyApp.AddEvent.AddEventMapActivity}:    
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
E/AndroidRuntime(16522): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line     #7: Error inflating class fragment
E/AndroidRuntime(16522):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
E/AndroidRuntime(16522): at  android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1892)
E/AndroidRuntime(16522): at com.project.MyApp.AddEvent.AddEventMapActivity.onCreate(AddEventMapActivity.java:20)
E/AndroidRuntime(16522): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
E/AndroidRuntime(16522): at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(16522):  at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(16522):  at  com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(16522):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:279)
```

while manifest looks like,

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.production.MyApp"
android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<permission
    android:name=" com.production.MyApp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name=" com.production.MyApp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" /> 

<application
    android:name="com.project.MyApp.MyApplication"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >

   <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="no issue with api_key here" />
```

and xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

while i am extending FragmentActivity,

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_layout);

    try {
        // Loading map
        initilizeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/**
 * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
 * */
private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the below to manifest file

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Place this at the end of your manifest, after your Map API key meta-data tag.

Check out [HERE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#add_the_google_play_services_version_to_your_apps_manifest)

It's a new requirement added from the last revision 13 update to google-play-services.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following in your manifest

```
 ...
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"  
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```

This information can be found in the logcat error msg.

And also on [google play services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Setup) website